# Erlang exit/2 bug in R15B03

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Short copy from [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-2):

> `exit(Pid, Reason) -> true`
>
> Types:
>
> Pid = `pid()`
>   Reason = `term()`
>
> Sends an exit signal with exit reason `Reason` to the process `Pid`.
>
> The following behavior apply if Reason is any term except `normal` or `kill`:
>
> If `Pid` is not trapping exits, `Pid` itself will exit with exit reason `Reason`. If `Pid` is trapping exits, the exit signal is transformed into a message `{'EXIT', From, Reason}` and delivered to the message queue of `Pid`. `From` is the pid of the process which sent the exit signal. See also `process_flag/2`.
>
> If `Reason` is the atom `normal`, `Pid` will not exit. If it is trapping exits, the exit signal is transformed into a message `{'EXIT', From, normal}` and delivered to its message queue.
>
> If `Reason` is the atom `kill`, that is if `exit(Pid, kill)` is called, an untrappable exit signal is sent to `Pid` which will unconditionally exit with exit reason `killed`.

I am playing around with the `exit/2` function and its behavior when `self()` is used as a `Pid` and `normal` as a `Reason`.

```
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> self().
<0.32.0>
2> exit(self(), normal).
** exception exit: normal
3> self().
<0.35.0>
```

Shouldn't it be the case that only a 'normal' exit message is sent to the shell process, so there is no reason to exit?

Similarly:

```
4> spawn(fun() -> receive Pid -> Pid ! ok end end). 
<0.38.0>
5> exit(v(4), normal).
true
6> v(4) ! self().
<0.35.0>
7> flush().
Shell got ok
ok
```

But:

```
8> spawn(fun() -> exit(self(), normal), receive _ -> ok end end).         
<0.43.0>
9> is_process_alive(v(8)).
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your third example shows if **any** process does an `exit(self(), normal)` then it crashes while doing `exit(AnotherPid, normal)` does not crash the other process. I have verified it on an R15B. I personally think that this is a bug as sending exit signal `normal` to **any** process should not result in its crashing.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Erlang shell ([shell.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl)) doesn't handle `'EXIT'` messages of type `normal` any differently than other exit messages, which means that it sends an error and restarts the shell. If you really want to find out this you can trace the program flow using the [debugger](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html) in this way:

1. Download [shell.erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html)
2. Change the filename to `shell2.erl`
3. Open the file and change the module name to `shell2` as well. You need to do this because the compiler will complain about `shell` being in a sticky directory.
4. Start the `erl` prompt.
5. `c(shell2, [debug_info]).`
6. `debugger:start().`
7. `Module -> Interpret` and pick shell2.erl
8. `shell2:start().`
9. Trace away!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason can be found from the source code 'stdlib-1.18.2/src/shell.erl'.

```
get_command(Prompt, Eval, Bs, RT, Ds) ->
    Parse = fun() -> exit(io:parse_erl_exprs(Prompt)) end,
    Pid = spawn_link(Parse),
    get_command1(Pid, Eval, Bs, RT, Ds).

get_command1(Pid, Eval, Bs, RT, Ds) ->
    receive
    {'EXIT', Pid, Res} ->
        {Res, Eval};
    {'EXIT', Eval, {Reason,Stacktrace}} ->
            report_exception(error, {Reason,Stacktrace}, RT),
        get_command1(Pid, start_eval(Bs, RT, Ds), Bs, RT, Ds);
    {'EXIT', Eval, Reason} ->
            report_exception(error, {Reason,[]}, RT),
        get_command1(Pid, start_eval(Bs, RT, Ds), Bs, RT, Ds)
    end.

report_exception(Class, Reason, RT) ->
    report_exception(Class, serious, Reason, RT).

report_exception(Class, Severity, {Reason,Stacktrace}, RT) ->
    Tag = severity_tag(Severity),
    I = iolist_size(Tag) + 1,
    PF = fun(Term, I1) -> pp(Term, I1, RT) end,
    SF = fun(M, _F, _A) -> (M =:= erl_eval) or (M =:= ?MODULE) end,
    io:requests([{put_chars, Tag},
                 {put_chars, 
                  lib:format_exception(I, Class, Reason, Stacktrace, SF, PF)},
                 nl]).

start_eval(Bs, RT, Ds) ->
    Self = self(),
    Eval = spawn_link(fun() -> evaluator(Self, Bs, RT, Ds) end), %%<========start a new shell pid
    put(evaluator, Eval),
    Eval.

severity_tag(fatal)   -> <<"*** ">>;
severity_tag(serious) -> <<"** ">>;
severity_tag(benign)  -> <<"* ">>.
```

For your first case (sending message to self()), the signal meets the 2nd situation of `get_command1/5`, it will give error message firstly, and spawn a new shell pid. Please pay attention to `start_eval` function.

For your second case (sending message to a spawn `pid`), Going back to your first part of post about the `exit` function, it is logical. Your spawned `pid` doesn't trap the exit message, and ignore the `(normal) exit` message. so the `shell` will receive exit message only when your spawn `pid`'s actual exit. It will go to the 1st condition of `get_command1/5`. Because `start_evel` is not been called, `shell pid` will keep the same.

For your third case, I don't know why. I also think `is_process_alive(v(8))` should return true.

Answer (score 0):

For the third case, the key point here is that self() is the pid of spawned process not the shell's.

see code below:

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
```

1> self().

<0.32.0>

2>  spawn(fun() -> io:format("This is ~p~n",[self()]),exit(self(), normal), receive _ -> ok end end).

This is <0.35.0>
<0.35.0>

3> is_process_alive(v(2)).

false

4>

Comment: I am aware of that. The point is that the spawned process sends to itself a normal exit signal, which shouldn't make it exit.

Answer (score 0):

It's all right there in the documentation that you quoted:

```
If Pid is not trapping exits, Pid itself will exit with exit reason Reason.
```

If you don't trap exits then your process will exit.

```
1> self().
<0.32.0>
2> process_flag(trap_exit, true).
false
3> exit(self(), normal).
true
4> self().
<0.32.0>
5> flush().             
Shell got {'EXIT',<0.32.0>,normal}
ok
```

There is no "message" being sent about exiting if you don't trap exits.  The process just dies.  As does any process linked to it.  This is what `trap_exit` is for.

Comment: Oh. I didn't read the full docs: `If Reason is the atom normal, Pid will not exit.`